# air conditioner unit

Tags: air-conditioning

I had a HVAC to came out said he put in 11 pounds it took 5 minutes. And he was smoking a cigarette sitting on the Unit while he was putting it in. I paid 1045.00

He also said he replace the evaporator which AHS paid for. Did I get ripped off? Sure feels like it.

Comment: Dunno. A thousand and forty-five what? Who's AHS? Also, price/service questions are off-topic on this network.

Answer (score 1):

If it is r22 that would be about the right price I know the shops are charging close to $100 per pound, if the system was running I could see maybe 1/2 that in 5 minutes maybe on a hot day (that just sounds a bit fast to me) is your system a 5 ton?  If smaller I don't think it could take 11 lbs of Freon unless totally flat and then it should have been pumped down. A very long line set may require more freon. As far as replacing the evaporator that would take hours to do. There will be a tag on your unit that stated the type of Freon and the required charge in pounds and ounces something like 13lb 8oz (I think that was the charge on a friends 5 ton I charged last weekend it took 8 lbs ) I do mostly industrial systems but help friends so I might be a bit more cautious than someone that charges several units a day. If it took 11 lbs of r22 I think the cost would be close to what the going price in Oregon is now.